# What does the Scattering Amplitudes tell us about the interactions of matter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics

I am confused as to the role of the wave function in quantum mechanics.  My understanding is that the wave function/state vector is purely a algorithm or mathematical means to compute the results of physical interactions.  However, the "scattering amplitudes" seem to model the interactions as collisions between "waves".  In other words, the wave equation evolves according to how the electron or other so-called particle traverses space and "collides" with either another electron or a crystal etc.(like the davisson-germer and even 2 slit experiment).

My question is whether the use of such terms as "scattering amplitudes" in quantum mechanics reflects actual scattering of physical waves of matter or whether it is a function of the evolution of the quantum wave function in some abstract mathematical space?  I at least know that scattering amplitudes represent probabilities.  So what process creates scattering amplitudes?  Is it the wave function of the particle with the wave function of the measuring device?  I don't understand how quantum mechanics explains scattering of matter.(Please excuse my ignorance about the mathematical details).  I am trying to get a physical model or operational model of how quantum mechanics describes scattering and how scattering amplitudes develop.  Or maybe a better question is what is the difference between classical scattering models and quantum scattering models?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. It isn't clear what you are asking here; you start talking about one topic, and end asking about a second. You might want to edit your question for clarity, so that you are more likely to get a good answer.